# Does the Taylor series of sinx divided by the Taylor series of cosx forms the Taylor series of tanx?

Tags: taylor-expansion

The question is in the title

if not, I'd like to know why it doesn't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, at least for $|x| \lt \frac{\pi}2$.  See for example the initial terms of [the expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expansion+of+(x-x%5E3%2F6%2Bx%5E5%2F120-x%5E7%2F5040)%2F(1-x%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E4%2F24-x%5E6%2F720)+at+x%3D0) and compare with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Tangent)

Answer (score 1):

It works, indeed but it is slightly tedious $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{x^{10}}{3628
   800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+O\left(x^{11}\right)}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{x^{10}}{3628
   800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)}$$ Now, long division to get $$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+\frac{17 x^7}{315}+\frac{62
   x^9}{2835}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any other way so it won't be tedious?(it's the fastest way I thought about)

Comment: @user401575. Yes, for sure ! The "normal" way avoids the long division. You always can compose series. Use the above to get $\cot(x)$.

Comment: What do u mean the "normal" way?  differentiating tanx is quite hard while   differentiating sinx and cos x is way easier

Comment: @user401575. I totally agree with you ! But, you are left with the lond division.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio does not write as a Taylor series directly. To do so, the product and composition rules are used. Recognizing the Taylor series $\frac{1}{1-u} = 1 + u + \dots$, one writes
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} &= \left(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \dots\right) \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \dots}\\
&= \left(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \dots\right)\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \dots\right) \\
&= x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \dots
\, ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which is the Taylor series of $\tan$.

An important point is convergence. The Taylor series of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are convergent all over $\mathbb{R}$, whereas the Taylor series of $\tan$ is convergent over $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$.

*Note*: another technique to obtain the Taylor series of $\tan$ consists in exploiting the fact that $\tan$ is an odd function, and the relationship with the derivative $\tan' = 1 + \tan^2$.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> **A recursive approach.**

$$
\sin\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}s_{n}x^{2n + 1}\,,\qquad
\cos\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{2n}\,,\qquad
\tan\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}t_{n}x^{2n + 1}
$$
where
$\ds{s_{n} = {\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}}$ and
$\ds{c_{n} = {\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n}!}}$

---

\begin{align}
s_{n} & = \bracks{x^{2n + 1}}\cos\pars{x}\tan\pars{x} =
\bracks{x^{2n + 1}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}c_{i}x^{2i}
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}t_{j}x^{2j + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{x^{2n + 1}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}
c_{i}t_{j}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\delta_{2i + 2j + 1,2k + 1}\,\,x^{2k + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{x^{2n + 1}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^{2k + 1}
\bracks{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}c_{k - j}t_{j}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\delta_{i,k - j}}\implies
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}c_{n - j}t_{j} = s_{n}}}
\end{align}

> From the last expression I'll get a recursive relation for $\ds{\braces{t_{j}}}$. Namely,

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{t_{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1}
\\
\ds{t_{n}} & \ds{=} & \ds{s_{n} - \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}c_{n - j}t_{j} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}!} - \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}
{\pars{-1}^{\,j} \over \pars{2n - 2j}!}\,t_{j}}\,,\qquad n \geq 1}
\end{array}\right.
$$